# Simple wordpress database php query not working

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm using this code here:

```
<?php
$post_id = 3651;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>
```

post id 3651 definitely exists, but I keep getting a server error.

The code is so simple - I looked at it many times but can't figure out what's wrong.

Am I using outdated functions or something?

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: This is an apache error, I seriously doubt this code has anything to do with the code you've provided unless you've added some hooks. I would first look at your `.htaccess`, turn it off and see if the 500 error is removed (might break other functionality but at least you've localised the error), then ensure that the syntax is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to include this line:

```
require_once("../wp-blog-header.php");
```

Thanks for those who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Apache web server and possibly a co-located server that has error reporting turned off in its configuration and you don't have access to change it, if at least `.htaccess` directives are allowed and you've got the ability to set the permissions on a log file via FTP or SSH, you could create and upload a blank `php_errors.log`, add the following directive to your `.htaccess` and then refresh the page you were on that was producing the error:

```
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /path/to/your/htdocs/php_errors.log
```

If the log file gets populated, please post the error and I'll update my answer with further assistance.